# Is there a way to prevent parsing responses that are redirected from another page?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using a CrawlSpider to scrape a site.  Some requests match a rule with a callback but are redirected to another page, and Scrapy is parsing these responses anyway.  Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but it seems that the `Requests.meta` object can have a `dont_redirect` property, which if you set it will likely solve your problem.

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#std:reqmeta-dont_redirect